# Different Value of Side $BC$ by Similarity and Pythagorean Theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

**Question :**

> In the given figure, $\angle ABC=90°$ and BD$\perp$AC. If $AB=5.7$cm, $BD=3.8$cm and $CD=5.4$cm, find $BC$.
> [image: Given Figure]

By similarity in $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle BDC$, (By $\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{BC}{DC}$ ) I got $BC=8.1$cm but by Pythagorean theorem I got $BC=6.6$.

Which one is right?

Comment: There is no correct answer. The given information is inconsistent.

Comment: You are getting two different answers as the dimensions given are incorrect for a right angled triangle.

Comment: Thanks. When I constructed triangel ABC with BC=8.1,I found CD 6.5cm and when I constructed ABC with BC=6.6cm, I found CD=4.9cm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this triangle does not exist!

Indeed, by the Pythagorean theorem we obtain: $$AD=\sqrt{5.7^2-3.8^2}.$$

Since $$\measuredangle BAD=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle CBD,$$ we see that: $\Delta ABD\sim\Delta BCD$ and we obtain: $$BD^2=AD\cdot DC,$$ which gives $$AD=\frac{3.8^2}{5.4}=\frac{361}{135}$$ and easy to see that $$\sqrt{5.7^2-3.8^2}\neq\frac{361}{135}$$

Comment: Can you explain the first step?

Comment: Which similarity criterion did you use?

Comment: @Mayank angle-angle

Comment: But in the $\triangle$ABD and $\triangle$BCD , only one angle is equal to other triangle i.e. 90°.

Comment: @Mayank Also, $\measuredangle BAD=\measuredangle CBD.$

Comment: But I am getting BC=8.1 when applying simmilarity in triangle ABC and BCD.

Comment: @Mayank I also used this similarity. It gives $BC^2=CD\cdot CA.$ See please better my solution.

Comment: I used the similarity in $\triangle ABC and \triangle BDC$ but you used similarity in triangle $\triangle ABC and \triangle BCD$ which are not similar. How are your triangles similar?

Comment: @Mayank I used this similarity exactly: $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta BDC,$ but you used $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta BCD,$ which is wrong and it gave a wrong answer. See please better your previous comment and my post: How I got $BC^2=CD\cdot AC?$ By your similarity or by mine? What do you think?

Comment: I accidentally wrote BCD in my previous comment

Comment: See my question

Comment: @Mayank I hope, now it's clear? $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta BDC$ gives:$\frac{BC}{AC}=\frac{DC}{BC}$ or $BC^2=DC\cdot AC.$ Probably, you used another similarity or a wrong proportion.

Comment: @Mayank No! See please better my previous comment. I think, the best way to understand your mistake it's the following. Write a proportion, from that you got your statement.

Comment: But If we use $\frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{BC}{DC}$ we would get BC=8.1cm

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: @Mayank Because this triangle does not exist! Wait, I'll explain it.

Comment: Yes I know I proved it by construction (When I constructed triangel ABC with BC=8.1,I found CD 6.5cm and when I constructed ABC with BC=6.6cm, I found CD=4.9cm. ).

Comment: Can you prove it theoritically?

Comment: @Mayank I proved it. See my post. If this triangle exists we get a contradictiuon.

Comment: Oh finally! Doubt cleared. Thanks a lot Michael.

Comment: @Mayank You are welcome! It was very interesting!